# TMUX pane not fitting to terminal size

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, tmux, window

I am trying to use tmux on Kali linux and I maximize my terminal size. When I start tmux with the following command the pane does not fit to the terminal size: `tmux new -s session`
As seen in the screenshot below it leaves out a huge chunk of the terminal width. This makes it not usable for me, especially if I want to split the window into multiple panes.

[image: tmux pane size issue]

I created a .tmux.conf with the following lines in my homedir. But it doesn't change anything.

```
set -g window-size latest
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize on
set -g window-status-current-style bg=black,fg=red
set -g base-index 1
set -g mouse on
```

I also tried to run the command `<c-b>:resize-window -A` mentioned in one other thread here. But to no avail. I did check the other threads here mentioning seemingly similar issues. But I couldn't find anything that helped.

The tmux version in use is version 3.3.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Based on the answer In checked the following:
Both vi and top do not use the whole terminal width as well. But what bothers me, I just use the Kali default. I didn't change anything there from the default installation. Therefore the terminal emulator defaults to qterminal. If I check $TERM it states xterm-256color.

I tried to switch to the Debian default terminal via Kali's system settings. But the problem remains with that terminal emulator as well.

I also set a fixed width for the terminal via its own settings to 1000px. Doesn't change a thing either. As for the font it says Cantarell 11pt.

Comment: What version of Kali? Also, do you have a high-res monitor? It may be related to high-DPI scaling. You can check your monitor settings or try an alternative terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your problem is not related to tmux. Try different apps, such as the `mc` file manager, `top`, your favorite text editor etc. I'm sure their layout all falls apart in a similar manner.

Based on the screenshot, you are using a variable width font, combined with a terminal emulator that just prints each row's characters one after the other without aligning them to the grid.

Terminals are supposed to have a strict grid of character cells. You should choose a fixed width font, and/or you should use a terminal emulator that sticks the characters to the grid even if they happen to vary in width. Preferably both.

(Just for curiosity: which graphical terminal emulator is it?)

Comment: I checked the Kali settings and it defaults to qterminal. If I check $TERM is states xterm-256color.